# pip3 install [package] failed no matter with proxy or without proxy

Tags: proxy, python3, socks5

**Environment**

Windows 1903 WSL (kali) python3.7

**Description**

when using `pip3 install flask` the output display like such

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyE
rror('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7
d8da46ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))': /simple/flask/
```

**Addtion**

there is not setting environment variables in wsl.

Comment: The error "cannot connect to proxy" means that you cannot connect to your proxy. You should check the proxy settings.

Comment: but i never set any proxy

Comment: and i have delete the cache and config as well as reinstall pip3